# Firebird update tableA set a=10/3 with 6 decimals

Tags: sql, firebird

When I type a sentence like this:

```
update tableA
    set tableA.a = 10/3
```

The value written is 3.33

But I need a six decimal lenght (field is double precision). 
I have also tried:

```
update tableA
    set tableA.a = round(10/3, 6)
```

and also:

```
update tableA
    set tableA.a = cast(10/3 AS DECIMAL(17, 6))
```

getting the same value (3.33) written on the DB
Please help to get the right instruction to write 3.333333

Comment: What is the datatype of column `a` and what is the dialect of your database?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Firebird 3. In a dialect 3 database this yields 3 as expected because dialect 3 applies integer division, and in a dialect 1 database this yields 3.33333... as expected because dialect 1 applies floating point division. Please provide all information necessary to reproduce this: Firebird version, database dialect, exact DDL and the exact code to reproduce this and how you come to the conclusion it shows `3.33` (some GUI tools take liberties when displaying values). As a workaround use `10/3e0`.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the database storage with the value that you see.  If you want to see 6 decimal places, then query it as:

```
select cast(a as decimal(17, 6))
from tablea;
```

when you query the value.

To make this "permanent", change the data type:

```
alter table tableA alter column a type decimal(17, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks but the column datatype is ok. It has other values with 6 decimals.

Comment: @carlos - then consult you programming language manual how to convert float value to formatted string with the format you need